# Renaming contact on Google Hangout

Tags: google-hangouts

How I can rename a contact on Google Hangouts? Some of my friends use more than one account and I'd like to renamed them for ease of use (recognition).

If is it not supported, where I must submit request future development?

Answer (score 0):

I have to do this on mobile. I create a new contact for each person and each app. Example - John Smith uses Google hangouts with his email - johnsmith@gmail.com and also sends SMS messages from his phone number. 555-555. I have to create two separate contacts. John Smith hangouts and John Smith text and then fill out the appropriate contact information. Once this is done, this updates Google hangouts on web as well.

Source - I'm a project fi Android user and this exact situation happens to me with multiple people not named John Smith.

Edit - just tested this and it appears their display names are pulled directly from their Gmail account. So you can edit who they are in contact form, but may not be able to change their display name.